# Weird "Changes you requested to the table..." Error in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a weird issue regarding a text box within a subform that is within the form i am working on.  Usually, I do not get this error when I would normally close out of the form via the Close button that was created on it.  If I was to close the form via the tab when I'm doing edits, it causes the error and using the Close button stops it when I reopen it.  I have no idea how to fix this so closing it through the tab would also not cause this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the close button works properly and closing the tab does not, then the close button does more than just close the form. Look at the OnClick code for the close button and transfer the appropriate part of it to the OnClose event of your form.

Most likely it is just something like `Me.Dirty = False` that writes any unsaved edits to the record but there may be more to it.

Comment: oh, I never thought of the onClose event (silly of me).  I've started using Access for a few months and working on a project that has been handed down to me from others.  Thank you for the answer.  If this fixes the problem when I get back to it I will mark this answer as correct.

Comment: Yeah, that stopped it from doing that error.  Thank you so much for the help.